# How do I fix style of my sliding pseudo class?

Tags: html, css

While the pseudo class is sliding out we can see that its left corners overlap the initial border of element. I wonder how I can fix this?

```css
.item {
      width: 400px;
      height 100px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 15px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .item::before {
      content: "";
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      border-radius: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      background: red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transform-origin: left;
      transition: all 3s;
    }

    .item:hover::before {
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div class="item">
    <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium dolorum aliquam dolor nisi quaerat cum?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPD: Also I have noticed that when the transition completes there are small gaps between pseudo class and the border of element. Any ideas on this?

Comment: You can fix it by adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.item`. Also you're missing a colon after `height`

Comment: The reason this occurs is because of the calculation method of the `border-radius` when `scaleX(0)` is transitioning, the border radius is being calculated to scale up to the `border-radius` value (`15px`) but it only achieves that once it reaches `scaleX(1)`.  
 There are ways to mask this as other comments/answers have suggested

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue where the left corners of the pseudo class overlap the initial border of the element.

```css
  .item {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .item::before {
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all 3s;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  }

  .item:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium dolorum aliquam dolor nisi quaerat cum?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use border-box instead

```css
  .item {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .item::before {
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all 3s;
    clip-path:border-box;
  }

  .item:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium dolorum aliquam dolor nisi quaerat cum?
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```